# To more understanding

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Under which conditions we  can  say that :

$
v'(t)\leq w'(t)
$
Implies that 
$
{v}{\mathrm{(}}{t}{\mathrm{)}}\mathrm{\leq}{w}{\mathrm{(}}{t}{\mathrm{)}}
$

Is there any explanation? .thanks very much thankful.

Comment: I'd use $$\int_{t_0}^t \left(v'(x) - w'(x)\right)dx \leq 0$$ for all $t \geq t_0$.

Answer (score 1):

We have a theorem, which is a direct consequence of the *Mean Value theorem*:

> Let $f,g$ functions defined in an interval $I$, $t_0\in I$. If
>
> (i) $\:f(t_0)\le g(t_0)$,
>
> (ii) $f'(t)\le g'(t)$ for all $t\in I$, $t>t_0$
>
> then for all $t>t_0$, $\;f(t)\le g(t)$.
>
> Furthermore, if one of the inequalities in (i) or (ii) is strict, the resulting inequality is strict.